# i have a problem with my code it wont work

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]

so I need to make 5 sliders using html but I have a problem with my code it worked in the first
slider ( the number are changing ) but in the other sliders the number wont change

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="slider">
      <input type="range" name="eng1" min="0"  max="180" value="20">
        </div>
            <div class="value">180</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    const slider = document.querySelector("input");
    const value = document.querySelector(".value");
    value.textContent = slider.value;
    slider.oninput = function () {
        value.textContent = this.value;
    }
    </script>
</body>


<body>
        <div class="box2">
            <div class="slider2">
                 <input  type="range"  name="eng2" min="0"  max="180" value="30">
            </div>
                <div class="outcome">180</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const slider2 = document.querySelector("input");
            const value = document.querySelector(".outcome");
            value.textContent = slider.value;

            slider.oninput = function () {
                value.textContent = this.value;

            }

                </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Images of code are not allowed.

Comment: i think your code is always selecting the first input, but since we are missing code replicating the problem is hard. please add the relevant code in a working snippet

Comment: I add a working snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelector selects the first it finds.
So, both querySelectors will go through the document from the top, find the first input tag  and item that has the class "value" and works with that. Which means both will select and work with the same slider and div.

Add:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="slider">
      <input type="range" name="eng1" min="0" max="180" value="20">
    </div>
    <div class="value">180</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="slider">
      <input type="range" name="eng2" min="0" max="180" value="30">
    </div>
    <div class="value">180</div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  const slider = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  const value = document.querySelectorAll(".value");

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    value[i].textContent = slider[i].value;
    slider[i].oninput = function() {
      value[i].textContent = this.value;
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

You shouldn't put several script and body tags. I renamend all to the same class and just use a loop in the script.

Comment: I tried to change the value class in the second slider to 2 but it didn't work

Comment: It's hard to help without any useable code just looking at a screenshot. Please add a working snippet to the post.

Comment: sorry I didn't know how to add a working snippet but now I did and I add it

Comment: @hadeel check the edit of my answer.

Comment: Now, add as sliders in as you need. But you need to change the "2" used in the loop, else it won't work. You could hardcode the number, since you also hardcode the amount of sliders anyway.